# Unable to run django custom command

Tags: python, django

I've create a command in app/management/commands and this command was working fine. I'm unable to run this command now. I'm getting the following error:

Unknown command: 'my_custom_command_name'

I'm using a virtual env. I don't see this in list of commands when I type `pythong manage.py`. I've this app installed in my settings and It was working previously

Comment: check if the following files exists: 
app/__init__.py
app/management/__init__.py
app/commands/__init__.py 

The manager might not be able to import those modules.

Comment: if you go to you django shell   **./manage.py shell** com you do an import app ? and does your app/ contains any models.py file?

Comment: And you're running `python manage.py` with the virtualenv activated? And the app is in the python path?

Comment: is your app still in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's really weird. When I tried to run:

```
$ python manage.py shell
```

I got the following error:

```
Error: cannot import name urandom
```

I searched for the error and found that I need to recreate my virtual env so I used the following command:

```
virtualenv /path/to/my/virtualenv
```

and then I was able to use django commands or my custom command the usual way :s

Answer (score 8):

Sufficient conditions:

**1)** The management command **can be imported** by:

```
$ python manage.py shell
>>> from yourapp.management.commands import yourcommand
```

(If it can't be imported then you probably easily get more details about the specific import problem. An answer can be eventually much easier searched or it is usually very trivial.)

**2)** The app implementing a management command for Django should be **installed as a directory** with individual files, **not compressed** into egg file. You can use the keyword parameter `zip_safe=False` in `setup.py` for preventing zipped installation. (This parameter is frequently not necessary if the `False` value is recognized correctly by autodetection. So it is even more surprising in other cases.)

Comment: For more fine-grained debug where the problem is you can try the imports one at a time. "import yourapp", "import yourapp.management", "import yourapp.management.commands".

Comment: Yes, I summarized the first condition the shortest possible way because wasimbhalli confirmed the question about correct imports yet.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this can happen if you haven't added your app to

`INSTALLED_APPS = [ 'app', ]`

in `settings.py`